# Can't update kernel on dual boot machine

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, refind

I have a dual boot MacBook Pro (2012). To install ubuntu 16.04 I followed this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/) using rEFInd. I made a mistake the first time so I reinstalled.  I now have two entries pointing to a single ubunutu partition (legacy & legacy on FAT) and one option for os x.
The issue I'm having is upgrading the kernel from 4.15.0-42-generic to 4.8. Again I followed a [guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-linux-kernel-4-8-ubuntu-16-04-16-10) and it seemed to work - until I rebooted and the version (using `uname -r`) was still 4.15.
I had a quick look at how I could manually force an update of the kernel and headers but it looked like it could go south pretty quickly ..so here I am. 
In the /boot directory there are both versions (4.15 & 4.8) but there is only a grub subdirectory. 
Any help upgrading the kernel would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @user535733 oh my bad. I thought the versions were like a decimal system. Is that why it didn't go to 4.8 - because it auto-detected a newer version?

Comment: @user535733. Really appreciate you pointing that out for me. Will go and read the docs on version numbering (although this will burn it into my brain...). How do I close the question (leave/answer/delete)?

Comment: Left an answer to make things easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, 15 is higher than 8.

4.15 is the newer kernel, and Ubuntu will understandably try to boot from it.

Different projects number their versions differently, so this answer is specific to kernel versions.